# How configure pop-ups in ArcGIS Online for open there attachments?

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments

Is it possible to open attachments by dint of pop-ups (as files jpg, doc)? According to this [Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Configure_pop_ups/010q0000004m000000/) – it’s possible:

“Pop-ups can be configured to show attachments as links if the map includes a features layer that has attachments in its data. You will only see an option to show attachments if the layer has them. When the pop-up is displayed, the attachment links are listed at the bottom of the window. Clicking one of the links opens the attachment in a new window”

But they don’t explain how to browse theme **with attachment** to ArcGIS Online. How I can do it, if shp theme can’t have attachment, but to ArcGIS Online from ArcGIS it’s possible to browse only shp file as a zip folder.?

Comment: I found an answer on the same question on the ArcGIS Forum (2011), it seems that it’s impossible (in spite of description this possibility in ArcGIS Online Help). As I understood, in ArcGIS Online it’s possible to demonstrate attached file only as a link in a pops-up window or in attribute table of a layer. Am I right? 
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43184-Newbie-uploading-attachments-to-ArcGIS-Online